# setResourceValue NSURLFileProtectionKey can't work

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, security

I need to continue to write the log when the device is locked. I wrote the Objective-C code below.

```
- (BOOL)setFileNSFileProtectionNone:(nonnull NSString *)filePath
{
    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString: filePath];
    if (fileURL != nil) {
        
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [fileURL setResourceValue:NSURLFileProtectionNone
                                      forKey:NSURLFileProtectionKey
                                       error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"setFileNSFileProtectionNone error: %@", error);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I called `setResourceValue` to set `NSURLFileProtectionKey` to `NSURLFileProtectionNone` after test.log0 is created, and the return value was `ture`.

```
func applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable")
    
    let logPath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: "Documents/log")
    
    if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: logPath) {
        for case let file as String in enumerator {
            let fullpath = logPath + "/" + file
            let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fullpath)
            var rsrc: AnyObject?
            do {
                try fileUrl.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey: .fileProtectionKey)
                print("BecomeUnavailable: \(file):\(rsrc)")
            } catch let e {
                print(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I called `getResourceValue` when the device is locked, I got `NSURLFileProtectionComplete`.

```
BecomeUnavailable: test.log0:Optional(NSURLFileProtectionComplete)
```

Why is it that `setResourceValue` can't work?

Comment: Maybe something to dig there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003762/ios-access-file-with-data-protection-after-user-locks-a-device

Comment: Yeah, I want to change the protection to `NSURLFileProtectionNone ` since I need to access this file when the device is locked, but the point is `setResourceValue` can't work, the file is still `NSURLFileProtectionComplete `.

Comment: I don’t think you can do that. You probably need NSURLFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen

Comment: Btw why are you using NSURL in Swift?

Comment: I need to continue to write the log when the device is locked, will try `NSURLFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen` to test again

Comment: `setResourceValue` to `NSURLFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen` can't work either.